# Jquery: Append text from textarea to html structure

Tags: jquery, textarea, append

I have a textarea that serves as input for text. When clicking a submit button, I want that text to be introduced in an html post structure, and that post (the html+text) to be appended to a list as a new post/comment.

JS:

```
var post= $('.small-textarea').val();
$("#comment-feed-list").append('<div> some text' + post +  'end</div>');
```

I am not being able to do it with success.

Is this an effective way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you submit the form, assuming that it is submitting to itself, you lose the DOM changes. It's like writing then erasing over.

Comment: A problem to consider is that "post" will only be temporary; refreshing the page would remove any "posts".  May want to connect this idea with some sort of database. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing it on submit, you have to prevent the actual submit event from happening

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var post= $('.small-textarea').val();
  $("#comment-feed-list").append('<div> some text' + post +  'end</div>');
});
```

The more common case is to prevent the submit, then send an ajax request to update the server behind the scenes and then append data to the DOM in a success callback or whatnot.